# Как выводить с помощью ORM данные из базы SQLite без интернета?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm

Я использую: `Retrofit 2`, `Active Android(ORM)` и `SQLite`.
Сервер написан на `Java + Spring`

**Приложение должно работать так:**
1. При доступном интернете - спарсить **JSON** и положить их в **SQLite** (в память телефона) и вывести их в **RecyclerView**
2. При доступном интернете - если произойдут какие-то изменения на сервере, например добавятся товары или категории, то приложение должно скачать измененные/добавленные товары или категории.
3. Если интернета нет - все данные из **SQLite** (в памяти телефона) должны вывестись в **RecyclerView**

У меня возникла проблема с двумя последними пунктами: в интернете не нашел нормальной документации где объясняется как заставить active android работать в оффлайн режиме, что для этого нужно делать, а также как сверять есть ли изменения на сервере.
Подскажите пожалуйста где можно почитать на счет этой синхронизации с сервером и оффлайн режимом телефона, может быть есть какой-то пример кода. Может быть есть какая-то документация для новичков?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы описывает это `Offline-first`. Т.е. вся инфа по умолчанию доступна без интернета, отображается из локального хранилища а при соединении с сервером полученная от него инфа лишь обновляет оную в локальном хранилище.

Как вы будете хранить инфу локально и как обновлять её с сервера - отдельный вопрос. Локально можно в БД хранить (SQL или NoSQL), а обновлять либо переодически делая запрос на сервер или с сервера рассылая пуши на девайсы с самой инфой или с целью побудить девайс эту инфу от сервера самостоятельно получить.

Лично я у себя использую `Realm` - `NoSQL` БД с уведомлениями в рантайме об изменениях выборки. Изначально всё из неё отображаю, а когда что-то на сервере поменялось, то оно пишется в БД и БД автоматом вызывает метод перерисовки `RecyclerView`.

Comment: У меня сейчас на сервере стоит бд postgresql, если я буду использовать Realm, мне придётся заменить postgresql на realm бд? Как пойти по пути наименьшего сопротивления для новичка? Может быть есть рядом пару статеек как это дело все провернуть? Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Бд на сервере и в приложении могут быть разными. Доки реалма будет вполне достаточно

Comment: спасибо! буду использовать тогда Realm, вроде как прост в использовании, если я не ошибаюсь.